# Convert string into JSON in Python

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I have this simplify array to be converted into JSON. For some reason, it does not working.

```
import json
arr = "[{u'symbol': u'YTLREIT', u'code': u'5109', u'name': u'YTL HOSPITALITY REIT'}]"
data = json.loads(arr)
```

The error I received,

`ValueError: Expecting property name: line 1 column 3 (char 2)`

Comment: Where is this data coming from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*This is not a valid JSON*, but you can load with [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> literal_eval(arr)
[{u'symbol': u'YTLREIT', u'code': u'5109', u'name': u'YTL HOSPITALITY REIT'}]
```

Comment: Thanks. It works! It looks like a valid JSON. What makes it not a valid JSON?

Comment: @geckob the extra `u` sign before the quotes and the quotes themselves - they have to be double quotes. It actually looks like a string representation of a list. If you have control over the tool produced it, you should tweak it to produce a valid JSON - if Python, `json.dump` or `json.dumps`.

Comment: @alecxe What is the reason behind putting double quote ? why not single quote?

Comment: @NamitaMaharanwar: That's just [JSON syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Data_types.2C_syntax_and_example). Strings **must** be delimited with double quotes.